# How to avoid struts2 action auto fire when page load

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to strtus2. I have developed web project with strtus2. In landing page, there is a login form and I can call the action by submitting the form. Problem is when I load the landing page that action also call and give exception as below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Initial capacity must be at least one but was 0
```

What can I do?

Comment: *What* action? Pages should (essentially) always be running through an action--sounds like you have something wrong with how your app is architected.

Comment: when load the page login action also call automatically without submitting login form. that's the problem.